# how to keep input text and value different in html

Tags: php, html, css

I am designing a form in which i have an input text field,

And my text is of the following type,
*abc-112233*

scenario for new record -

I want first 4 characters of text to be fixated/non-editable in the field, ie. "abc-" and user can type number coming after the hyphen, but when the form gets submitted, i want it to get submitted as **abc-** 112233, not just 112233.

Hence in short, i want the text to be shown as 112233 (abc- fixed) inside the input, but value after submission should be whole "abc-112233".

scenario for previous record to be updated -

and for when the input field is pre-filled according to records in database, ie. when the record needs to be updated, i want to show it as **abc-** 112233

my code is according to following,

```
<div class="">
    <label for="inputError" class="">Name</label>
    <input 
         type="text" 
         id="" class="form-control" 
         name="name" 
         value="<?php 
                     if(isset($data->name)){ 
                         echo $data->name; 
                     } else{  
                         echo "";  
                     }
                ?>" 
         required
     > 
</div>
```

right now, the value is,

```
$data->name
```

which is abc-112233.
and the text shown inside the input is also abc-112233,
I want the text to be 112233(with abc fixated/non-editable on left hand side) and the value to be abc-112233

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is really two questions in one. How to make the input display "abc-123" with the user only able to change the "123" part, and how to submit it as "abc-123". The most straightforward way to satisfy both is to actually put the "abc" part in the input and use JavaScript to make sure the user can't change or delete it. Are you interested in JavaScript, or is that not an option?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do it within only 1 <input> element, maybe you can try separated into 2, one is fixed for "abc-" and the other is for user input. Then you can control whether to show / hide the fixed one.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using pseudo code to display the prefix.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.demo:before {
  content:"abc-";
}
```

```html
<label for="demo">Demo input</label>
<span class="demo"><input id="demo" type="text"></span>
```

Comment: to expound upon your answer, what if they used JQuery .prepend() or prependTo() to achieve this. They would need to set an ID or ad an additional class to their input. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach:

```css
body, input
{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.editable
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px 2px 2px inset;
}

.editable > input
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.editable::before
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    top: 5px;
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable" data-placeholder="ABC- ">
    <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

you will need to play with the CSS a bit to get it to look right. I presume you are using Bootstrap based on your ".form-control" class.

Basicly this is just forcing content to overlay on top of your input. not inside of it. otherwise you will need to prepend or append content to the input value using JavaScript